# Do I need to register a domain with an OAuth2 provider, like google, or can use my own IP address/Localhost to send requests?

Tags: javascript, google-api, localhost, oauth-2.0

I can't push my code to my domain and have been testing up until this point on my local web server, 127.0.0.1. But can I avoid registering a domain with the OAuth2 providers, and send requests from my IP address?

So far, I've done all research, but I've seen no indication that is is not possible. I've also seen no explicit information that it is.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The title does not really say it all. Please define better what "my address" is (server or client?).

Comment: If look at my computers information and find out what my IP address is. @deceze

Comment: So, your *client's*, totally unrelated to your server, IP address? Nope, not possible. Why?

Comment: @deceze Because we don't have a server/host. I have a domain name, I have a local webservice and local storage. I can test most of my application without the need to move to a server. But now that I want to implement OAuth2, I'm surprised there is no alternative for people who simply want to test locally without pushing their entire app to their server/host.

Comment: @deceze i would like to add..could I register my IP address with the OAuth2 provider instead of a domain?

Comment: Now I gotcha. It was pretty hard to understand what you want. So you just want to know how to locally test an Oauth2 implementation *without a domain whatsoever*. I'm not familiar with Oauth ***2***, but in Oauth 1 you could typically register any fake domain, including `localhost`. Doesn't that work?

Comment: It took me an entire hour to understand this concept. I just registered a "domain" (my IP address, actually) with google OAuth2 provider. I'm going to test it now. @deceze being inexperienced, I assume something is not going to work before I try it and do my best to research it until Im sure it will. For some reason this was not clear to me before.

Comment: @deceze I'll edit my question, you should answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register any domain, including `localhost` for local testing.

The Oauth server will not contact that domain by itself. It will only redirect users back to that domain as part of the authentication process, which works just fine when you test it locally with `localhost`.